# Checkerboard Infection Problem minimal initial infection needed

Tags: discrete-mathematics, game-theory

This problem has been brought up here a couple of times so I'm doing a copy and paste for the introduction:

“There is a dangerous bacteria, Checkerichia Coli, (or C. Coli for short) which lives in the squares of checkerboards. Squares with this bacteria living in their digestive systems are said to have "C-sickness". Once a square has "C-sickness," it is stuck with it forever!

Excessive contact with C-sick squares will cause a square to become C-sick. Specifically, if a healthy square has at least two C-sick neighbors (orthognal, not diagonal), then that square becomes C-sick the next day.

For example, on the left we the photo of a see a partially infected checkerboard which was taken yesterday. On the right is a photo taken today.”
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pq9cJ.jpg)

The original question under this problem was "If the terrorist has only 7 samples, can he still infect the whole board?“ which has been proven by comparing the maximal parameter of each case and thus finding out the minimal number of initially infected squares required to eventually infect the entire board. **Is there a way to generalise this problem(proving this mathematically, finding out a formula for the process, etc)? Could we then extend this generalisation to a 3D cube(the infection rule could tweak a little, for instance requiring a block to border 3 instead of 2 already infected blocks in order to be infected) and find out the minimal number of initially infected blocks required in order to eventually infect the entire cube?**

Context: this is a task given by my teacher in high school.
My tries: I couldn't figure out a mathematical proof but have proved through exhaustion that the minimal initially infected blocks needed to eventually infect the entire cube is $2n-1$ if a blocks gets infected when bordering two already infected blocks, and $n^2$ if it needs to border three. I haven't studied discrete mathematics so inputs on this regard(proof by case analysis) would be greatly appreciated as well:)

Original post: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/18074/checkerboard-infection

Comment: By the linked answer, you need at least $64$ pieces. I suspect that $(1,1,1),(1,2,2),\ldots,(1,8,8),(2,2,1),(2,3,2),\ldots,(2,8,7),(2,1,8),(3,3,1),(3,4,2),$ and so on will do it, but I'm too lazy to write it out right now.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Thats also the answer I got via exhaustion(n*2). How did you obtain it though? Also my calculations took only the number into account without their orientations, so I'd really appreciate if you could elaborate on that:)

Comment: For the necessary part, observe that in every step the total surface of the infected part can never increase. Hence you need at least the surface of the whole cube ($8 \cdot 8 \cdot 6$) at the beginning. One little cube has surface $6$, so you'll need at least $8 \cdot 8$ little cubes. For the sufficiency part, I only played it through in my head, but obviously I may have made a mistake. It's probably easiest to write a short program to test it instead of proving it by hand.